# Opening local HTML project shortcut from tablet desktop with Chrome

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android, html

Trying to create shortcut to my html project on my tablet desktop. I've use File Manager/File Shortcut etc from Play Store to create the shortcut. My problem is my best option with "complete action using" when tyring to open it is HTML Viewer which doesn't really cut it.

Anyway way to do what I'm doing but open it with Chrome?
running android 4.1.1